# Is location.protocol ever invalid?

Tags: javascript

I want to construct URLs with the same scheme (presumably, "http:" or "https:") as the page that loaded the currently-running JavaScript. Modern browsers support simply omitting the scheme (for example, `src="//example.com/test.js"`), but this isn't fully cross-browser compatible. (I've read that IE 6 is the only browser that doesn't support it, but I still need compatibility with that version.)

The cross-browser way to do this seems to be to check `location.protocol`. For example, Google Analytics uses:

```
('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + ...
```

In Google's case, they wanted to use different domains depending on whether the request uses SSL, so that pattern makes sense. But I've seen others use the same pattern even when only the protocol is different:

```
('https:' == location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//example.com"
```

(One example is in the "Final Wufoo Snippet" at http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/.)

I'd prefer to use this simpler expression instead:

```
location.protocol + "//example.com"
```

Should I really be concerned about the possibility of `location.protocol` taking on some value other than "https:" or "http:" when my code is used on sites I don't control?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will always be set to something, but it may sometimes be set to a value that is neither "http" or "https". The three other values you're most likely to see are `file:` (for HTML files), `about:` (for iframe magic involving `about:blank`), and perhaps `ftp:`.

Comment: Oh, does iframe magic include cases where people programatically construct an iframe and then populate it from the parent frame's JavaScript? Now that you mention it, although I can imagine `file:` and perhaps `ftp:` coming up from time to time, I bet iframe magic is the most common case.

Comment: Correct -- that's exactly where you'd be most likely to run into the `about:` protocol.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This is not strictly about document.location.protocol's return being valid or not but describes a very hard to spot bug (you can override the behaviour of document.location.protocol without writing any javascript).

I've bumped in to one seemingly strange case where **document.location.protocol** did not seem to work as it should. The site had a tracking-Javascript which used the following snippet to resolve the current protocol:

```
var proto = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://')
```

The site was on HTTPS but on some pages the protocol would turn out to be **http** instead of the expected **https**.

After a lot of time spent in Googling and investigating the application stack configuration, one developer spotted that the pages the protocol resolving problem occurs, have **a HTML-form with the following attribute:**

```
name="location"
```

This caused the protocol resolution to misbehave and incorrectly deduce the protocol to http instead of https (no, the form did not have a field called protocol nor it should have).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I found this exact problem with my code, and had no idea why document.location.protocol was "http:" when it was supposed to be HTTPS. Seems so counter intuitive - why is it not just analysing the address bar string in browser??? weird.

Comment: Because if there's a form with the name `location`, then `document.location` is the form element, which has no `protocol` property at all. Thus, `'https:' === document.location.protocol` is false.

Comment: Uese the proper `location` global instead of the old `document.location`. Browsers always had both, there is no point in using `document.location`.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I really be concerned about the possibility of document.location.protocol taking on some value other than "https:" or "http:" when my code is used on sites I don't control?

Not particularly, but then again, there's no particular harm in your approach (pre-pending whatever the protocol is) instead. Google Analytics probably does the actual detection as much because they use a different host as anything else.